# What is the point of having an alliance with your partner's family?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I've been playing *Mount & Blade: Warband* on PS4 for about 2 years and I've never really understood what an alliance does with your partner's family.

I own a lot of castles and 2 towns and I have a really good relation with my wife's father (relation with father is 97), but I've done that by doing quests for him and her mother. I haven't talked to her yet and have 0 relation with her. I have a 67 relation with my wife.

Her dad hasn't helped me in any fights and mostly votes me for castles, villages, and towns. So does anyone know what an alliance with your partner's family does?

Comment: I’m not confident enough to post it as an answer, but I’m pretty sure it improves your Right to Rule